# Passing parameters through AsyncTask - android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to pass an integer through a AsyncTask for use in the doInBackground on click of button.

Here is my passing the parameters

```
public void go(View view) {

    EditText input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtInput);

    int downloads = Integer.parseInt(input.toString());

    ProcessTask myTask = new ProcessTask();

    //5000 - number of Ms to simulate download

    myTask.execute(5000, downloads);

}
```

and then here is where I try to use those same values I pass

```
    private class ProcessTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Void>{

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Integer myD = params[1];


    for(int i = 0; i<myD; i++){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(params[0]);
            publishProgress(i+1);
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I keep getting the following errors:

```
    04-20 19:10:43.198: E/AndroidRuntime(4363): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 19:10:43.198: E/AndroidRuntime(4363): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-20 19:10:43.198: E/AndroidRuntime(4363):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633)
04-20 19:10:43.198: E/AndroidRuntime(4363):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
04-20 19:10:43.198: E/AndroidRuntime(4363):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
04-20 19:10:43.198: E/AndroidRuntime(4363):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
04-20 19:10:43.198: E/AndroidRuntime(4363):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-20 19:10:43.198: E/AndroidRuntime(4363):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-20 19:10:43.198: E/AndroidRuntime(4363):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-20 19:10:43.198: E/AndroidRuntime(4363):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 19:10:43.198: E/AndroidRuntime(4363):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-20 19:10:43.198: E/AndroidRuntime(4363):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-20 19:10:43.198: E/AndroidRuntime(4363):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-20 19:10:43.198: E/AndroidRuntime(4363):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-20 19:10:43.198: E/AndroidRuntime(4363): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-20 19:10:43.198: E/AndroidRuntime(4363):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 19:10:43.198: E/AndroidRuntime(4363):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-20 19:10:43.198: E/AndroidRuntime(4363):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
04-20 19:10:43.198: E/AndroidRuntime(4363):     ... 11 more
04-20 19:10:43.198: E/AndroidRuntime(4363): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "android.widget.EditText{41754410 VFED..CL .F...... 32,110-736,188 #7f080002 app:id/txtInput}"
04-20 19:10:43.198: E/AndroidRuntime(4363):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
04-20 19:10:43.198: E/AndroidRuntime(4363):     at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
04-20 19:10:43.198: E/AndroidRuntime(4363):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
04-20 19:10:43.198: E/AndroidRuntime(4363):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
04-20 19:10:43.198: E/AndroidRuntime(4363):     at com.example.asyncfinalpractice.MainActivity.go(MainActivity.java:30)
04-20 19:10:43.198: E/AndroidRuntime(4363):     ... 14 more
```

any and all help is much appreciated. I'm kind of new to android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `getText()` call in your method chaining.

It needs to be `input.getText().toString()`.

The clue is the logcat output:

> Invalid int: "android.widget.EditText{...

That is definitely *not* your input.

For number parsing, I'd recommend actually `catch`ing the Exception. That way any input that you might have forgotten to filter does not crash the program.

Comment: Thanks so much! it's the little things you miss sometimes.